# Return function as function with parameter as shown sample code in Java for android

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio

After running a functions, it will return a or more result, and I'll use it on another functions as the parameter.

```
Internet2 internet2 = new Internet2();
internet2.run((res1,res2)->{
    Log.d("result 1", String.valueOf(res1));
    Log.d("result 2", String.valueOf(res2));
});
```

wish help of experts here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found answer and wish to share for all users,
we can create an class of Internet2.java and code like

```
package io.jibon.comparemarketrecipts;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Internet2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final TaskListener taskListener;

    public interface TaskListener {
        public void onFinished(String result);
    }

    public Internet2(TaskListener listener) {
        this.taskListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return "afterDoSomething()";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(this.taskListener != null) {
            this.taskListener.onFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call like this

```
Internet2 task = new Internet2(result -> {
    // Do Something after the task has finished
});
task.execute();
```